# How display name at header facebook post when share to facebook in php

Tags: javascript, facebook

How to display my website name at header facebook post, when sharing my article from my website to facebook in php? like below image,

[image]

below is my code,

```js
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Testing">
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.Testing.com/Testing.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Testing topic" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="About the workshop:
This workshop is the first collaborative workshop bet..." />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.Testing.com/Testing.html" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.Testing.com/Testing.html" data-layout="button" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.Testing.com/Testing.html" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: what is there at the moment?

Comment: This is called the App Attribution, and would link to the app that the post was made through. However, I am not sure if you can get that for posts that are made using any of the Share options, I think that was only for when an app posted on a user’s behalf via API (which is not possible any more.)